# Can't prepare INSERT statement with subquery

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to prepare the INSERT query in PHP script and always getting the FALSE result:

```
$mysqli -> prepare(
'INSERT INTO `shopping_cart_data`(`cart_id`, `type`, `item`, `size`, `cost`) '
. 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?,?,?,?,?) AS tmp '
. 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `shopping_cart_data` WHERE `cart_id`=? AND `item`=?) '
. 'LIMIT 1'
);
```

The $mysqli->errno is 0 and $mysqli->error is empty too.
When I replace the query parameters with actual values and execute this query in phpMyAdmin it works just fine.

**Edit #1**
mysqli->prepare() fails even on simplified version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO `shopping_cart_data`(`cart_id`, `type`, `item`, `size`, `cost`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?,?,?,?,?) AS tmp LIMIT 1
```

Please help.

Comment: What values are you trying to insert?

Comment: 'sssid': something like 'sdgsi2492lksjfsdf', 'type_x', 'item-name', 100, 5. But the problem occurs at the prepare stage, not at the bind_params.

Comment: Two things: One, what happens if you add "FROM DUAL" to the non-table subquery? That's the placeholder table for queries where there's no actual table. Two, what happens if you just do "SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?" instead of "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"? The two are identical.

Comment: @Andrew Thank You. I corrected the query and now everything works.

Comment: You also don't need the "LIMIT 1" there.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Andrew's comment, the problem was solved with query correction. The working version of the query is:

```
INSERT INTO `shopping_cart_data`(`cart_id`, `type`, `item`, `size`, `cost`)
SELECT ?,?,?,?,? FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `shopping_cart_data` WHERE `cart_id`=? AND `item`=?)
```